Why is my discord (nextcord) embed not displaying what I want?
player1 = None
player2 = None
turn = None
gameOver = True
board = []
game_board_message = None
count = 0
 
winningConditions = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
]
 
winningConditions = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
]
 
@bot.command(aliases=["ttt"])
async def tictactoe(ctx, p2: nextcord.Member):
    global player1, player2, turn, gameOver, board, game_board_message
 
    player1 = ctx.author
    player2 = p2
    gameOver = True  
 
    if player1 == player2:
        await ctx.send("You can't play with yourself!")
        return
 
    if gameOver:
        invite_message = await ctx.send(f"{player2.mention}, you have been challenged to a game of Tic Tac Toe by {player1.mention}! Respond with `s!at {player1}` to accept the challenge.")
        gameOver = False
        board = [":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                 ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                 ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:"]
        turn = player1
        game_board_message = None  
    else:
        await ctx.send("A game is already in progress! Finish it or end it using **s!sttt** before starting a new one.")
 
@bot.command()
async def at(ctx, challenger: nextcord.Member):
    global player1, player2, turn, gameOver, board, game_board_message
 
    if ctx.author == challenger:
        await ctx.send("You cannot accept your own challenge.")
        return
 
    if ctx.author == player2 and challenger == player1 and not gameOver:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} has accepted the challenge from {challenger.mention}. Game started!")
        gameOver = False
        board = [":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                 ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                 ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:"]
        turn = player1
        game_board_message = await send_game_board(ctx)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Invalid command usage or the game is not ready to start.")
 
async def update_game_board(ctx):
    global board, player1, player2, turn
   
    description = ""
    for x in range(len(board)):
        if x == 2 or x == 5 or x == 8:
            description += " " + board[x] + "\n"
        else:
            description += " " + board[x]
 
    if turn == player1:
        description += f"\nIt is {player1.mention}'s turn."
    elif turn == player2:
        description += f"\nIt is {player2.mention}'s turn."
 
    embed = nextcord.Embed(
        title="Tic Tac Toe",
        description=description,
        color=0x00ff00
    )
 
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
async def send_game_board(ctx):
    global board, game_board_message, turn
    description = ""
    for x in range(len(board)):
        if x == 2 or x == 5 or x == 8:
            description += " " + board[x] + "\n"
        else:
            description += " " + board[x]
 
    if ctx.author == turn:
        description += f"\nIt is {ctx.author.mention}'s turn."
    else:
        description += f"\nIt is {turn.mention}'s turn."
 
    embed = nextcord.Embed(
        title="Tic Tac Toe",
        description=description,
        color=0xFF0000
    )
 
    if game_board_message:
        await game_board_message.edit(embed=embed)
    else:
        game_board_message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    return game_board_message
 
@bot.command()
async def place(ctx, pos: int):
    global turn, player1, player2, board, gameOver, game_board_message
 
    if gameOver:
        await ctx.send("Please start a new game using the s!ttt command.")
        return
 
    if ctx.author != turn:
        await ctx.send("It is not your turn.")
        return
 
    mark = ":regional_indicator_x:" if turn == player1 else ":o2:"
 
    if not 0 < pos < 10:
        await ctx.send("Be sure to choose an integer between 1 and 9 (inclusive).")
        return
 
    if board[pos - 1] != ":white_large_square:":
        await ctx.send("This position is already taken. Choose another one.")
        return
 
    board[pos - 1] = mark
 
    await send_game_board(ctx)  
 
    try:
        await ctx.message.delete()  
    except:
        pass
 
    if check_winner(mark):
        winner = player1 if mark == ":regional_indicator_x:" else player2
        await update_game_board(ctx)
        await ctx.send(f"Congratulations {winner.mention}, you won!")
        gameOver = True
    elif check_tie():
        await ctx.send("It's a tie!")
        gameOver = True
    else:
        turn = player2 if turn == player1 else player1
 
 
def check_winner(mark):
    global gameOver
    for condition in winningConditions:
        if board[condition[0]] == mark and board[condition[1]] == mark and board[condition[2]] == mark:
            gameOver = True
            return True
    return False
 
def check_tie():
    global count
    count += 1
    if count >= 9:
        return True
    return False
 
@bot.command()
async def sttt(ctx):
    global gameOver
 
    if gameOver:
        await ctx.reply("You have no ongoing game at the moment.")
    else:
        gameOver = True
        await ctx.reply("Game ended.")
 
@tictactoe.error
async def tictactoe_error(ctx, error):
    print(error)
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please mention 2 players for this command.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please make sure to mention a player. (e.g: s!ttt @sky)")
 
@place.error
async def place_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please enter a position you would like to mark.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please make sure to enter an integer.")
# https://pastebin.pl/view/5849f6b2 (the code)

So basically, I made a tic tac toe game but the problem is that the Embed that "shows the game" works, but  the "description += f"\nIt is {player2.mention}'s turn." doesn't. It does, but instead of it being player1, player2, player1, player2 etc... it's instead player1, player1, player2, player1, player2, etc. It is really annoying.
To be honest, I've tried pretty much everything I could possibly think of. Re-wrote pretty much all my code, changed functions, logic, let's just say A LOT (5 hours). I really don't know if it's a pretty big problem or just a silly noob like mistake that I just didn't notice. I can't say I'm the best with python (especially when it comes to making discord bots).

Hey there and welcome to stackoverflow, I recommend you to create a minimal reproducible example, get rid of unnecessary game logic and simplify your code while the problem remains observable. That would help to focus on code that matters.
